# Django UpdateView CheckboxSelectMultiple - How do I load an object's ManyToMany field in CheckboxSelectMultiple?

Tags: django

My UpdateView draws from a ModelForm where the sport_prefs field loads as CheckboxSelectMultiple.  The form loads correctly and submits data to the MemberRecord model successfully.

My issue is in the UpdateView even though the sport_prefs field shows up as checkboxes, it does not load the current object sport_prefs field's data.  The checkboxes load as blank and while I can select options and it will update and save correctly, I cannot load the sport_prefs data from when it was first created or last updated.

models.py

```
class SportOptions(models.Model):
    sport_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MemberRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(ContactInfo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    join_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    sport_prefs = models.ManyToManyField(SportOptions)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

forms.py

```
class createForm(ModelForm):
    sport_preference = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=SportOptions.objects.filter(),
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
            )

    class Meta:
        model = MemberRecord
        fields = [
            'name',
            'age',
            'join_date',
            'sport_preference',
            'notes'
        ]
```

My guess is I created a new CheckboxSelectMultiple field and I load the correct options because I draw from the SportOptions model but I do not draw from the specific object's sport_prefs.  This shows true when I change the ModelForm 'sport_preference' back to 'sport_prefs' as it loads the data correctly but it does not load as CheckBoxSelectMultiple.  I am guessing I need to pass the object id through the query set filter in sport_preference if I want to load the data as checkboxes?  If so, how do I do that?

Comment: The name of the field is `sport_prefs`, so you should use *that* field name.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the answer!  How do I show the field as CheckBoxSelectMultiple though?EDIT-NVM I saw your response on the other post, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the field is `sport_prefs`, so you should use *that* field name. If you want to use a different *label*, you can specify a [**`label=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#label):

```
class createForm(ModelForm):
    sport_prefs = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label='Sport preferences',
        queryset=SportOptions.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MemberRecord
        fields = [
            'name',
            'age',
            'join_date',
            'sport_prefs',
            'notes'
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I show the sport_prefs field as CheckboxSelectMultiple though?  Because the default ManyToMany field shows as a multi-select and I would prefer the checkboxes!

Comment: @jonayoung: you keep the `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple`?

Comment: @jonayoung: the problem is not with the widget, but with the fact that the name of your field did not map on the name of the model field.

Comment: Apologies, I re-read your response.  I changed what you explained and it works.  Thank you so much Willem!!